# how to use self reference in typescript object?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to edit a TypeScript file that - obviously - I didn't write, and I'm getting hung up on the syntax. It's currently doing stuff like:

```
import type { Serverless } from 'serverless/aws'

const serverlessConfiguration: Serverless = {
    environment: {
        CRM_BASEURL: '${self:custom.crm.${opt:stage}.baseUrl}',
        CRM_TENANTID: '${self:custom.crm.${opt:stage}.tenantid}',
    }
}
```

I get what `self` and `opt` are referring to there and what they're doing (`opt:stage` value is a label for the environment, e.g. "dev" or "uat"), although I've no idea what the colon syntax is called or how it's working.

But anyway, what I'm trying to do is create a similar config object but passing a boolean value instead of a string. Something like:

```
tracingEnabled: {
    lambda: self:custom.tracingEnabled[opt:stage],
},
```

Obviously that's wrong; VSCode lights it up with enough red underlines to bathe my desk in a soft red glow. But what's the *right* syntax?

Thanks :)

Comment: `'${self:custom.crm.${opt:stage}.baseUrl}'` - this has nothing to do with JavaScript/TypeScript. That's a special syntax used by AWS (I guess). So why do you think it would be `self:custom.tracingEnabled[opt:stage]` (which doesn't look right) and not again a string?

Comment: Thanks - yeah I'm just trying to figure out *what* this syntax is, and since it's a TypeScript file and I'm not too familiar with TypeScript syntax, I assumed that's what it was. And absolutely yes, my crude attempt to take the object literal tags from around it was an effort to illustrate what I'm trying to do rather than an actual solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Right. Yep, I'm an idiot. This is - as @Andreas points out above - nothing do do with JavaScript/TypeScript. It's being resolved by [Serverless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless) which I guess makes it [some sort of JSON schema](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/configuration-validation/), or something. Honestly, I've no idea. But at least I know what it IS now.